# Does anyone have any frameworks to setup custom post types and related actions/filters?

Tags: custom-post-types, framework

So I know that setting up custom post types ranges from just registering them to adding custom permalinks, custom sorting, customizing columns in the admin, etc.  I was wondering if anyone had a template or framework that they use regularly to set up custom post types in projects?  Do you start from scratch every time or do you have a base line you start from that you customize?

Comment: I was running this from scratch every time and it was quite time consuming. I built a framework for this last week and it's saved me a ton of time already. I'll push it to the plugin repo in a week or two and I'll comment here with a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Custom Post Type Demos](https://github.com/toscho/Custom-Post-Type-Demos) by toscho hold some nice basic classes, that you can use. I'd recommend taking a look at this source (as he's a *trusted author* and a pretty good coder).

Answer (score 1):

There is the promising [Piklist](http://piklist.com) which does a lot more than CPT (settings, widgets)

All in a fashionable way and very easy to maintain. (I'm not the author)

Comment: I just started using Piklist and so far I'm very impressed

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to check [PODS](http://pods.io/), its very powerful and useful, with deep relations and very easy to use. It save a lot of time and.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tending to just write code directly for adding Custom Post Types now, but I have used Easy Post Types (http://easyposttypes.com) before, I've found however that they've been slow to bring out updates and never responded to any bug reports I sent to them. I'd also suggest checking out the Magic Fields plugin (http://magicfields.org), since V2 it uses CPTs and offers a lot of useful features.